# Network load each 5 seconds

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, countdowntimer

I need to make a network request every 5 seconds to update a list with data. I'm thinking of the best way to do it in Android/Kotlin.
I was advised to use CountDownTimer with onTick() and onFinish methods. But I'm not sure if it's going to work well in my case because the timer will be started once in onCreate() method in activity but I need the job to start/finish every 5 seconds.
Could you advise, please?

Comment: how about using runnable?? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler

Comment: If you want to request every `X minutes`, even if your `Activity` is in the background, foreground or killed, you should consider using [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) or [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an CountDownTimer, but you should take care that the networktraffic is on a background thread.

Or you can use Alarmmanager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager, maybe if you want to start a service even if your app is in background?

```
val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

val intent = Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
        5 * 1000,  // 5 seconds
        pendingIntent)
```

Or an Handler would work like this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler

```
val handler = Handler()
val runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        // Perform network request
        // Update UI if necessary
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5 * 1000)  // 5 seconds
    }
}
handler.post(runnable)
```